# If a theory is 1-consistent then it is consistent

Tags: logic, incompleteness, meta-math, metalogic

I am attempting to back two claims in this problem:

I use $\textbf{Q}$ to denote minimal arithmetic for this post.

I use the term 'rudimentary sentence' to denote formulas built using only negation, conjunction, disjunction, and bounded quantifications. It has been pointed out to me that these are more formally called $\Delta_0$ sentences. Additionally, '$\exists$-rudimentary' refers to $\Sigma_1$ sentences.

> A theory $T$ is 1-consistent if for all $\exists$-rudimentary sentences of the form $\exists x$ $F(x)$ , if $T\vdash \neg F(0)$, $T\vdash \neg F(1)$, $T\vdash \neg F(2)$,... then $T\not\vdash\exists x$ $F(x)$.

To show:
If $T$ is 1-consistent, then $T$ is consistent.

~~~~~~~~~~~~

From this point on, I assume that $T$ is a 1-consistent theory.

I use a function now $Prv_T(x)$ to mean $\vdash_T A$ if and only if the sentence $Prv(\ulcorner A\urcorner )$ is correct under the standard interpretation.

Let $T$ now be a 1-consistent ($\Sigma_1$-sound) theory extending minimal arithmetic.

I let $G$ be such that

$T \vdash G \leftrightarrow Prv(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$.

To show: $T\not\vdash \neg G$.

I apologize in advance if this is unclear, I am not yet totally comfortable communicating this material.

Comment: Is "rudimentary sentence" your own word? It sounds like you're defining what is usually called $\Delta_0$ sentences, and your "$\exists$-rudimentary sentences" must be $\Sigma_1$ sentences.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It is probably an informalism, I am following Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey, _Computability and Logic_.  I apologize for this, I'll add it in.

Comment: By the way, the natural continuation of your $G$-based reasoning is [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b's_theorem) which says (under suitable assumptions) that if $T\vdash G\leftrightarrow Prv(\ulcorner G\urcorner)$ then $T\vdash G$. But in order to get the last step from $T\vdash G$ to $T\not\vdash \neg G$, you need to already know that $T$ is consistent, so I don't think you'll actually make progress that way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I apologize! You are very correct on that - for the second part, I am to operate under the assumption that $T$ is a 1-consistent ($\Sigma_1$-sound) theory extending minimal arithmetic (I will add that in now). Would Löb's theorem now apply?

Comment: x @faux: I think Löb's theorem _applies_ (if you have enough machinery available to construct your $G$ in the first place, which I'll assume) -- I'm just doubting that it's _helpful_ for your goal of proving $T$ consistent.

Comment: From what I understand, these are two related but independent problems; showing first that if T is 1-consistent then T is consistent, and then assuming if T is 1-consistent that $T\not\vdash\neg G$

Comment: x @faux: Hmm, as far as I read the question, the problem you're trying to solve is "Show that if $T$ is 1-consistent then $T$ is consistent", and all the stuff about $G$ is something you came up with yourself in an partial attempt to solve that problem. If this is not the case, you need to edit the question and _add prose to make clear what the heck it is you're trying to achieve_, instead of leaving it to the reader to _guess_ which the train of thought connects the fragments you're deigning to write down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39718/discussion-between-faux-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: There's not really anything to chat about. It's your job to make sure the questions you ask are clear. Since it now appears that everything you have written is just a copy from a problem sheet somewhere and you're never actually speaking _to_ the audience here, nor providing any thoughts of your own, I'm voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: $1$-consistency and $\Sigma_1$-soundness are not "obviously" the same thing: their equivalence must be proved (under suitable assumptions).

Answer (score 2):

Your diagonalization ansatz seems to be overkill for this purpose.

Instead simply consider that in an inconsistent theory *everything is provable*. So if $T$ is inconsistent, you can let $F$ be any formula whatsoever; the premise of your definition of "1-consistent" will then be satisfied but the conclusion is not. So it is impossible for a theory to be inconsistent yet 1-consistent.